# Setting up Code Contracts in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-contracts

So I was trying to run some simple code with Code Contracts (that I haven't used for some time)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double res = sqrt(-5);
    }

    static double sqrt(int a)
    {
        Contract.Requires(a >= 0, "a must be >= 0!");

        return Math.Sqrt(a);
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything at all when I run it. From what I recall from some months ago, it should throw up an error about `a` being less than 0.

I reinstalled the Academic version from the Code Contracts site just to be safe and this still doesn't seem to be working. What are the steps needed to put Code Contracts to work?

EDIT: Resharper is telling me on `Contract.Requires(a >= 0);` that the method is being skipped, as it is either "conditional or a partial method without implementation".

Thanks

Comment: I guess you want to write Math.Sqrt(a) instead of Math.Sqrt(a*a)? Of course, this doesn't help with your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this web page: [link text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/i-just-installed-visual-studio-2010-now-how-do-i-get-code-contracts-melitta-andersen)

You should go to the project properties, Code Contracts tab and click the Runtime checkboxes.